# Allowing Automatic Logins from a Range of IP Addresses

Tags: users

I'd like to implement the following functionality in my site:

Give an entire organization access to our Drupal 7 site from a specific range of IP addresses.

The way it would hopefully work is this: users in the organization, from any of the computers in their organization (in the ip range) would be able to go to our site and be automatically logged in.

Other users with individual accounts in our system should not be restricted from logging into our site.

Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you actually need the drupal login functionality? If not you could do what you wanted with htaccess and basic authentication

Comment: I don't think I need Drupal login functionality per se. The idea is the user would sit down at their computer in the ip range (think a library) and would click a link on their computer to go to our site...it would take them to our site and because they're IN the ip range it would just auto-log them in and their 'username' would be the library name. And of course multiple people should be able to do this simultaneously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [IP Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_login)

> This module allows users to login automatically via their IP (v4)
> address ranges or wildcards instead of having to enter a username and
> password - plus many other features.

Comment: This looks promising! Do you know, if the 'user' were an organization for example, and several people from the org. might be trying to login at the same time to our Drupal site, if it allows this? ... I seem to recall with a regular Drupal account if you try to login with the same user account on two different browsers it detects it and denies the second user. But maybe it's already reading my ip and only preventing multiple logins from the same IP...

Comment: `I seem to recall with a regular Drupal account if you try to login with the same user account on two different browsers it detects it and denies the second user` never had that problem. I've done it in two different browsers even with diff IP and no problem login in. (not using IP login module)

Comment: Alright very good, yea you're right. Hmm not sure what I was remembering there. But thanks for your advice!